# Double Accuracy

Tags: java, double

I need some help, this is the code I'm referring to:

```
int myId; 
my Id = 20113275l
int numLet; 
numLet = 6;
double doubleResult; 
doubleResult = 10000 + (80 + ((myId - 123456) / ((numLet + 20)*(numLet + 20))      )); 
System.out.println("Expression 5: " + doubleResult);
```

According to my calculator, the answer should be 39650.7, but when I run the program it's giving me 39650.0

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

Comment: Add the language tag. Yes it is clear it is a java, but just to make sure.

Comment: try `doubleResult = (double)(10000 + (80 + ((myId - 123456) / ((numLet + 20)*(numLet + 20)))`

Comment: Everything in your expression in an integer, so the arithmetic uses integer rules. Thus the division is an integer division, which is truncating.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `double` values only to get the wanted result in this case :

```
int myId; 
myId = 20113275;
int numLet;
```

Becomes

```
double myId = 20113275.0;
double numLet;
```

And here is the output :

```
Expression 5: 39650.73816568047
```

Comment: @JamesKPolk You're right, I did not see the "l" at the end and therefor was mislead

Answer (score 0):

You're getting integer division, because none of your parameters are `double`. The result of dividing two integers is an integer. And your type is an `int` (adding an `l` at the end promotes to `long`). Anyway, cast one of the terms to a `double` and you'll get the result you expect. For one decimal of precision you can use formatted output. Something like,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int myId = 20113275; // <--- Not a long.
    int numLet = 6;
    double doubleResult = 10000 + //
        (80 + ((myId - 123456) / (double) ((numLet + 20) * (numLet + 20))));
    System.out.printf("Expression 5: %.1f%n", doubleResult);
}
```

Output is (as you requested)

```
Expression 5: 39650.7
```